# Hide an element with the exact same classes

Tags: html, css, display

How can I apply `display: none;` to the fifth element (with the title 'SumoMe') and make sure that only SumoMe is hidden?

If I use a `.sumome-share-client-animated.sumome-share-client-share { display: none; }`, all five elements disappear since they have identical classes.

```html
<div data-sumome-share-pos="lp" class="sumome-share-client sumome-share-client-left-page sumome-share-client-light sumome-share-client-medium sumome-share-client-circle">

<a title="Facebook" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/facebook-black-60.png" alt="Facebook"></a>

<a title="Twitter" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="twitter" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/twitter-black-60.png" alt="Twitter">

</a><a title="Google+" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="googleplus" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/googleplus-black-60.png" alt="Google+"></a>

<a title="LinkedIn" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/linkedin-black-60.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>

<a title="SumoMe" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe"></a></div>
```

Comment: Add an individual `id` attribute to it, and then select that id

Answer (score 8):

Utilise the `attribute selector`.

```
a[title="SumoMe"] { 
    display: none;
}
```

Working example:

```css
a[title="SumoMe"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div data-sumome-share-pos="lp" class="sumome-share-client sumome-share-client-left-page sumome-share-client-light sumome-share-client-medium sumome-share-client-circle">

<a title="Facebook" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/facebook-black-60.png" alt="Facebook"></a>

<a title="Twitter" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="twitter" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/twitter-black-60.png" alt="Twitter">

</a><a title="Google+" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="googleplus" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/googleplus-black-60.png" alt="Google+"></a>

<a title="LinkedIn" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/linkedin-black-60.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>

<a title="SumoMe" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe"></a></div>
```

Documentation on the [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Use `nth-child` to select the 5th element with the class `sumome-share-client-share` and hide that using `display: none;`

```css
.sumome-share-client-share:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
  }
```

```html
<div data-sumome-share-pos="lp" class="sumome-share-client sumome-share-client-left-page sumome-share-client-light sumome-share-client-medium sumome-share-client-circle">

<a title="Facebook" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/facebook-black-60.png" alt="Facebook"></a>

<a title="Twitter" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="twitter" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/twitter-black-60.png" alt="Twitter">

</a><a title="Google+" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="googleplus" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/googleplus-black-60.png" alt="Google+"></a>

<a title="LinkedIn" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/linkedin-black-60.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>

<a title="SumoMe" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe"></a></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `nth-child(5)` if you know it is the fifth element:

```
.sumome-share-client.sumome-share-client-left-page.sumome-share-client-light.sumome-share-client-medium.sumome-share-client-circle > a:nt-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can work with attribute-selector:

```
.sumome-share-client.sumome-share-client-left-page.sumome-share-client-light.sumome-share-client-medium.sumome-share-client-circle > a[title=SumoMe] {
    display: none;
}
```

Or you can set an `id` and use the # id selector:

```
<div data-sumome-share-pos="lp" class="sumome-share-client sumome-share-client-left-page sumome-share-client-light sumome-share-client-medium sumome-share-client-circle">

<a title="Facebook" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/facebook-black-60.png" alt="Facebook"></a>

<a title="Twitter" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="twitter" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/twitter-black-60.png" alt="Twitter">

</a><a title="Google+" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="googleplus" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/googleplus-black-60.png" alt="Google+"></a>

<a title="LinkedIn" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/linkedin-black-60.png" alt="LinkedIn"></a>

<a title="SumoMe" id="foobar" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe"></a></div>
```

and

```
#foobar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Good recap of all possibillities!

Answer (score 0):

Change or add a class on the fifth element and then display none.

```
<a title="SumoMe" class="hide-me sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe"></a></div>
```

then in your css:

```
.hide-me {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reference it by its title, like:

```
[title=SumoMe] {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery selector [`.eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (`n=index number of target`). For demonstration purposes I've added a textbox and button that will use an inputted number as the target `<a>` to hide. The heart of the function is this expression:

> ```
> $('a:eq('+idx'+)').hide();
> ```

Which in more generic terms:

> ```
> $('a:eq(4)').hide();
> ```

would hide the 5th `<a>`.

**Note:** The additional form controls (`<input>` and `<button>`), are not required, they are there just to enter a number for demonstration. Assuming that IRL you will procure the number programmatically or hard coded which will essentially be:

> ```
>  $('a:eq(4)').hide();
> ```

Snippet has further details commented. Pick a number 0 to 4, then click the <kbd>**HIDE**</kbd> button.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// When button#hide is clicked...
$('#hide').on('click', function() {

  /* ...the string value of input#index
  || is converted into a real number and
  || stored in var idx.
  */
  var idx = parseInt($('#index').val(), 10);

  /* To determine which <a> to hide, use the
  || jQuery selector :eq(n) where 'n' is the
  || INDEX NUMBER (0 COUNT) of the <a>s.
  */
  $('a:eq(' + idx + ')').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='index' type='number' min='0' max='4'>
<button id='hide'>HIDE</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div data-sumome-share-pos="lp" class="sumome-share-client sumome-share-client-left-page sumome-share-client-light sumome-share-client-medium sumome-share-client-circle">

  <a title="Facebook" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/facebook-black-60.png" alt="Facebook">
  </a>

  <a title="Twitter" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="twitter" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/twitter-black-60.png" alt="Twitter">

  </a>
  <a title="Google+" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="googleplus" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/googleplus-black-60.png" alt="Google+">
  </a>

  <a title="LinkedIn" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="linkedin" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/linkedin-black-60.png" alt="LinkedIn">
  </a>

  <a title="SumoMe" class="sumome-share-client-animated sumome-share-client-share" data-sumome-share="sumome" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background: rgb(249, 199, 15); color: black; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <img src="//sumome-140a.kxcdn.com/static/e712458c65fa75b6aaa4f4f9880230c43c634ce5/client/images/apps/9e8a4d2a-6f8c-415e-851b-bdfe4c01d5c1/sumome-black-60.png" alt="SumoMe">
  </a>
</div>
```